# Why does the calendar icon not show up?

Tags: calendar

I have a problem, the calendar application icons are not visible after the eos installation. It does not even appear over time. I have reinstalled the system several times and in vain, it doesn't work. And there is no icon only in this menu, in the rest of the menu it is

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure you use the default them? for be sure follow this link https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13531/ive-changed-my-system-stylesheet-or-icons-and-things-broke-now-what

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AppCenter and install AppEditor
https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor

You can configure the App Icons for each app.
So just select the calendar icon for the Calendar app.

Idk why you face such problems though, maybe it's releated to the language you use.

Comment: It doesn't work, I change the icon to another, and it doesn't change. It's some kind of system glitch. Initial system installation changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is [an issue in Calendar](https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/477). I've filed an issue on GitHub; you can give that a ️ reaction to show you're affected, and you can use the **Subscribe** feature on GitHub to get a notification when there's an update.

Comment: This issue may only be for the Ukrainian version of Elementary OS. This problem needs to be addressed. I'm a simple user. It's my job to tell the developers what the problem is. And it's not my business to solve it.